# Partner unable to send email from a case

Tags: administration, permissions, page-layout, partner-portal, configuration

I have a partner portal user that, although the page layout assigned to their profile and record type that they are using for the case contains the email section (which by the way on the page layout editor says it is uneditable) but they cannot see this section when they view said case page layout. How do I enable the user to see the email section on the page layout?

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did the OP find a solution? Can anyone else help please?